# How does ? {$_.Status -eq "Running"} work (PowerShell)?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

The command for printing out 2 services that are currently running using powershell is

```
get-service | ? {$_.Status -eq "Running"} | select -first 2 | fl
```

I do understand the overall functioning of the command, but the part that confuses me is
`? {$_.Status -eq "Running"}`. I may be overthinking, but is there any specific meaning for those symbols(? _ . $).

Can someone explain how that part of the command works ?

Comment: you have just demoed why one should NEVER use aliases or shorthand names for code that will not be immediately thrown away. [*grin*] **_NEVER use an alias or a shorthand name for any code that will ever be read by anyone in the future - including by "future you"._**

Comment: Fully agreed :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Powershell the question mark is [an alias of Where-Object cmdlet](https://ss64.com/ps/where-object.html):

> The '?' symbol and Where are both aliases for Where-Object.

While `$_` is the result/output from the pipeline as stated [here](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-automatic-variables.html)

> Contains the current object in the pipeline object. You can use this variable in commands that perform an action on every object or on selected objects in a pipeline.

To reduce the amount of characters, instead of typing

```ps
Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"} | Select-Object -First 2 | Format-List
```

you can type using alias:

```ps
get-service | ? {$_.Status -eq "Running"} | select -first 2 | fl
```

or

```ps
gsv | ? {$_.Status -eq "Running"} | select -first 2 | fl
```